# How to set API headers for different APIs?

Tags: reactjs

I need to call 2 different APIs from my react app, and both of these APIs use different types of Authorization.

```
makeAPICall = (url, body, method, env) => {
    let requestOptions = {method, body, headers: {}};
    if (env === 'api_1') {
        requestOptions.headers = {'Authorization': `Token ${authToken}`}
    } else if (env ==='api_2') {
        requestOptions.headers = {'Client-Secret-Key': `${clientSecretKey}`}
    }
    url = new URL(url);
    return fetch(url, requestOptions);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, so that I don't have to send my api name in each api call (like I am sending `env` in makeAPICall function).

Is there a way of intercepting the api url, and setting headers accordingly?

Comment: The answers provided here are good, but I need to know, if I can update headers without having to provide api name.

Comment: My point is that if you don't want to judge the difference of `env` in the function, you can only do it before the function call

Comment: Ideally, make different functions for every API type.

Answer (score 1):

use this code is a better way i think, you can try it

```
const headers = {
  api_1: {'Authorization': `Token ${authToken}`},
  api_2: {'Client-Secret-Key': `${clientSecretKey}`}
}
requestOptions.headers = headers[env]
```

Comment: simple and straightforward answer